# Select Query without one row if statement

Tags: sql

I've a query that returns a result of few rows. Each row has id, first_name, last_name, position. I would like to modify this query to hide one person with position = 'Manager' if the person which runs this query on the web is of position = 'Manager'. So basically I would like to show all rows if the person logged in is not manager, but if the  person is manager then do not show row which has 'Manager' position.

Comment: Show us some sample table data, and also tell us which dbms you're using.

Comment: There are several problems here, which are bound up in the details of your application. The most important of these details is: how do you know whether the user running the query is a manager? That requires querying a table of user data, and maybe caching it or holding it in a variable. You need to provide a lot more details before your question is answerable.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `where` clause with *Boolean* expression :

```
where (@personlogged = 'manager' and position <> 'Manager') or
      (@personlogged <> 'manager');
```